# Cannot display implict EL(Expression Language) scope objects

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have created the servlet 'SetAttributes' as,

```
request.setAttribute("a1","v1");
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("a2","v2");
ServletContext application=getServletContext();
application.setAttribute("a3","v3");
request.setAttribute("c","request");
session.setAttribute("c","session");
application.setAttribute("c","application");

RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Process.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Now the Process.jsp is as follows,

```
a1, a2, a3 can be directly accessed as: ${a1} ${a2} ${a3}<br />

        Each attribute can also be accessed as: ${requestScope.a1} ${sessionScope.a2} ${applicationScope.a3}<br />

        Accessing the repeated attribute directly then the value will be for: ${c}<br />
        Common attribute can also be accessed as: ${requestScope.c} ${sessionScope.c} ${applicationScope.c}<br />

        Trying to access out of scope attribute we get: ${applicationScope.a1}
```

The value of the attributes i.e. 'a1','a2' and 'a3' are supposed to be displayed on my webpage but I'am getting a blank value.

Below is my output for Process.jsp,

```
a1, a2, a3 can be directly accessed as: 
Each attribute can also be accessed as: 
Accessing the repeated attribute directly then the value will be for: Common attribute can also be accessed as: 
Trying to access out of scope attribute we get:
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL displayed in the address bar of your browser when you get this output?

Comment: @JBNizet The URL is: http://localhost:8080/Expression_Language/Process.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting the JSP directly, without going through the servlet that sets all the attributes. So obviously, when the JSP is executed, all the attributes are null.

The URL in your address bar must be the URL of the servlet, and not the URL of the JSP.